# What the purpose of value-comparator in Vuetify v-select or v-autocomlete

Tags: vuetify.js

After providing a custom function to `value-comparator`, I have realized that **it's a way to decide which item should appear after** selection is made and the dropdown is closed.

Does this property serve any other purpose, i.e., `v-model` or `dim selected item`?

Comment: Interestingly the v-checkbox component has the same property.

Answer (score 5):

`value-comparator` controls which values are currently shown as selected in `v-select` and `v-autocomplete`.

[By default](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/612ca06bd6d0b73dc89186b9f0f2af3cb5e82d58/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/__tests__/VSelect.spec.ts#L329), it uses a strict comparison:

```
valueComparator: (a, b) => Math.round(a) === Math.round(b)
```

It serves a purpose in `v-model` in that it is used to determine whether the value passed to `v-model` is being correctly detected as "selected". For example, if the list of `items` passed to `v-select` uses integer ids as values, and the data value initially passed to `v-model` is a string, `v-select` will show that no value was selected. You can either cast the initial data value to a string, cast item values as strings, or explicitly set the compare function to one using a weak comparison (`==`).